# How to preserve seconds when Concatenating two Date_Time columns

Tags: sql, datetime, concatenation, max, milliseconds

I am getting the last update from two different columns. Either P1DT will be null or P2Dt will be null, and never both. I have successfully merged the two columns into one, but will need to preserve the seconds at the end of the number... what is the best way to go about this?

```
WITH tblDT AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        StudyNum,
        SerialNum,
        PuffCount,
        CONCAT((SELECT MAX(P1DT)
                FROM P3 P3B
                WHERE P3B.SerialNum = P3A.SerialNum
                  AND P3B.StudyNum = P3A.StudyNum),
               (SELECT MAX(P2DT)
                FROM P3 P3B
                WHERE P3B.SerialNum = P3A.SerialNum
                  AND P3B.StudyNum = P3A.StudyNum)) AS MaxDate    
    FROM 
        P3 P3A 
)
SELECT *
FROM tblDT
```

I tried concatenating the two columns into one. It works successfully, but does not preserve the seconds.

Comment: sample input and expected output please

Comment: If you can concatenate them, they aren't really datetime values at all. But what you really want is **`COALESCE()`**

Comment: Right.  The answer may be very simple.  If we had a clear question...

Comment: Tried to work through a solution, but still having trouble.  Why do you think you need to use `MAX`?  Why would PuffCount not be included in the join in your solution?  Maybe better:  What real-world question is your query intended to answer?  Something like, "What is the most recent date when a puff count was performed?"

Comment: Max should return the most recent date from that particular column based on unique SerialNum and StudyNum. the DB I am working has these values in separate tables that have to be coordinated via a third table.I combined everything together using a WITH clause And the resulting table is the one this query references, and is nothing more than the columns shown here. It was combined such that P2DT, and P1DT are completely separate i.e. if P1DT is NULL P2DT is NOT and the vice versa is also true. I will have to try tommorow, but it seems that COALESCE(P1DT,P2DT) is the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Please update your question.  Don't use the comments as part of your question.  And, Wow!  Basic SQL coding skills would help.  Maybe start here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SQL

Answer (score 1):

You want `COALESCE()` rather than `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT a.StudyNum, a.SerialNum, a.PuffCount
    , COALESCE(MAX(b.P1DT), MAX(b.P2DT)) MaxDate
FROM P3 a
INNER JOIN P3 b on b.SerialNum = a.SerialNum AND b.StudyNum = a.StudyNum
GROUP BY a.StudyNum, a.SerialNum, a.Puffcount
```

If you don't really need `PuffCount`, know it's always the same for a given `StudyNum` and `SerialNum`, or can otherwise infer it from an aggregate function, we can also remove the `JOIN`.

---

Hmm... thinking more, I think we can also do this with window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT StudyNum, SerialNum, PuffCount
    ,COALESCE(
       First_Value(P1DT) over (PARTITION BY StudyNum, SerialNum ORDER BY P1DT DESC),
       First_Value(P2DT) over (PARTITION BY StudyNum, SerialNum ORDER BY P2DT DESC)
    ) MaxDate
FROM P3
```

See them work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/gTyoBoRS

---

If the original query runs at all using `concat()`, with no casting, then *you don't really have DateTime values at all*. What you have are string/varchar values **pretending** to be DateTime values, and **that's really bad.**

Comment: "that's really bad"  Agreed.  Based on SQL problems posted on SO, I suspect there are a lot of databases out there that were designed by people who have not spent even 5 minutes learning data modeling.  I always assume that folks like Alex are stuck dealing with this idiocy with no authority to change the database structure.

Comment: I have no control over the DB structure. I don't want to reveal too much  because of confidentiality, but essentially there are two items with serial numbers and they each have their own table. there are A LOT of many to many relationships across dozens if tables, none of these items are unique in any table... it's very confusing lol